# TypeError: #<Promise> is not iterable

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I was trying to use promise.all to do multiple api calls but for some reason it it throwing the following error

> TypeError: # is not iterable

My Promise is fairly simple (this is probably the second time I am using Promise.all)

```
componentWillMount() {
    const id = this.props.location.pathname
    let axiosHome = axios.get('/home')
    let axiosUserData = axios.get("/profile/" + id)
    Promise.all(axiosHome,  axiosUserData).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

**Question:** Any idea why I could be getting this error? Also, can someone also explain when is that we use resolve keyword with promise?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`Promise.all` accepts a single argument, which is an *array of `Promise`s* - subsequent arguments are discarded. So, pass in an array instead:

```
Promise.all([axiosHome,  axiosUserData])
  .then(...
```

> when is that we use resolve keyword with promise?

`resolve` is not a keyword, it's just the conventional function name used when constructing a `Promise`:

```
const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // do some asynchronous stuff
  if (ok) resolve();
  else reject();
});
```

When a `Promise` is explicitly constructed like that, call `resolve()` to resolve the Promise. (of course, one could name the function argument anything, it doesn't have to be called `resolve`)

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all() accepts arrays of methods (async) and data can be assign to variables
as array

**Example:**

```
let [axiosHomeData , axiosUserData] = await Promise.all([axiosHome,  axiosUserData]);
```